# Email Regular Expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, mailto

I have an string and I need an email ID parsed from that string. I have used PHP regular expression for retrieving and worked fine. But my problem is if the email prefix contains the regex.

```
<?php
$convert = "mailto:xxxin@yahoo.inATTENDEE";

preg_match_all('/mailto:(.*?)(.com|.org|.net|.in)/', $convert, $emails);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($emails);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => mailto:xxxin
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => xx
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => xin
    )
```

)

But I'm expecting `[0] => mailto.xxxin@yahoo.in`. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`str_replace()`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://php.net/str_replace&ei=iK78UqLhJ6Peigeb8YHoAw&usg=AFQjCNGXfs7lE66mQ_wX46NfGr-rGHi6GQ&sig2=T1r_wkCnqTeIfinzkNAfeQ&bvm=bv.61190604,d.aGc) AND [`explode()`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://www.php.net/explode&ei=oq78UuuLL7CwiQf2_4GYCQ&usg=AFQjCNGaTqxol919mhhakO8YlFXjZV6_XQ&sig2=FMvvZK4DZrephXO_BMM9XA&bvm=bv.61190604,d.aGc) as:

```
$convert    = "mailto:xxx@yahoo.com, mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in";
$finalstr   = str_replace(array("mailto:", " "),"",$convert);
$emailids   = explode(",", $finalstr);
var_dump($emailids);
```

Comment: The given string will be repeated as different emails in an entire string.

Comment: $convert = "mailto:xxx@yahoo.com, mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in";

Answer (score 0):

```
$convert = "mailto:xxxin@yahoo.inATTENDEE";

preg_match_all('/(mailto.*(?:.com|.org|.net|.in){1}?)/', $convert, $emails);

$newArray = array();
foreach($emails as $em){
$newArray = array_merge($newArray, $em);
break;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in
)
```

Comment: I'm expecting [0] => mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do it for you:

```
<?php
//$convert = "mailto:xxxin@yahoo.inATTENDEE";
    $convert = 'mailto:xxx@yahoo.com, mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in';

preg_match_all('/mailto:.*?(?:\.com|\.org|\.net|\.in){1}/', $convert, $emails);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($emails);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Updated with that pattern, working, and removed extraneous brackets, working:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3if-8qy

Comment: Thanks. $convert = "mailto:xxx@yahoo.com, mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in"; Can I get it in array?

Comment: Remove the brackets outside your pattern so you dont have doubled values in your array: `'/mailto:.*(?:.com|.org|.net|.in){1}?/'`

Comment: For seperating with the comma use this pattern: `'/mailto:.+?@.+?(?:.com|.org|.net|.in){1}?/'` You get an array containing our mailto's